# Max Mind Geolocation anomalies

Tags: c#, geolocation, maxmind

I have a site that geolocates the user based on the IP Address using a MaxMind local database. I am finding the results on my desktop to be different than when on a phone. For example:

- I am geolocating using the X-Forwarded-For header
- My phone locates me in the zip code 18036, which is about 50 miles
  off.
- I look up the ip address on my phone using IPv4/IPv6 Dual-Stack Test
- Using a browser extension on a desktop, I set my X-Forwarded-For header to the same IP Address
- The desktop places me in 19428, which is still wrong but is MUCH
  closer to correct

Why is there a difference?

Here is how I am performing my lookup:

```
var ip = httpContext.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"];

CityResponse cityResponse;
using (_dbReader = new DatabaseReader(fullPath, FileAccessMode.Memory))
{
    cityResponse = _dbReader.City(ip);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Is your phone connected to the same WiFi as your desktop? Or is it connected over 3G/4G?

No. To ensure phone and desktop were looking at the same things:

1. My site explicitly looks at IP for location - I am not tapping into browser location services, which may use a variety of methods to determine your location.
2. When searching on my phone, I turned off wifi so it was definitely using 3G/4G
3. After locating on my phone, I retrived my phone's IP address using "What my IP" in a browser
4. I spoofed the phone's IP in my browser using the X-Forwarded-For header and ensured my website was looking at that header instead of the actual IP (which would have been an internal IP)

Comment: Is your phone connected to the same WiFi as your desktop? Or is it connected over 3G/4G?

Comment: Any explanation of the down vote? Honestly want to know so I don't do it again.

Comment: I downvoted since I asked a question that you didn't seem to answer. _You did **kind of** answer it in a comment against the below answer, but you didn't update your post with that information - to make it easy for others to find._

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Wifi, and on the same network as your computer, there won't be any difference because the public IP address (WAN IP address) will be the same.

If your phone is on a network other than the one your computer is on, there's no telling which ISP you would be assigned to (at the given time) and which IP address was assigned to your phone.  If a cellular tower happens to be down or overloaded, your connection would be

Comment: Desktop is on company network. Phone is on cellular network. But I checked my phone ip and then spoofed that ip on the desktop.

Comment: Can you try a different site?  Go incognito and try Google maps. See where that locates you based on the autocorrect suggestions.

Comment: Google maps is very accurate, but doesnt that use more than your ip?

Comment: Google maps sometimes users your wireless access point to determine your location bb